# Sort this data in excel kinda like a pivot

Tags: excel

All,

I have this data I pulled from a database that I need to readjust. Here it is:

```
ID | Type     | total
 1    Purchase   12
 1    Return     2
 1    Exchange   5
 3    Purchase   34
 3    Return     4
 3    Exchange   2
```

The desired result is:

```
ID | Purchase | Return | Exchange
 1      12         2         5
 3      34         4         2
```

and so on with a lot more data. Can this be done?

Comment: And why not a pivot table?

Comment: Can this be done a pivot table? I tried yesterday and had no luck but if you think so I will mess with it some more.

Comment: Yes it can be done.  Put the ID as rows the Type as columns and the total as values.

Comment: I did that however for the values I get counts. I don't want counts but the actual values to show.

Comment: @Icebreaker Assuming you have only one `total` value per unique pair of `ID` and `type`, you have to use `Sum of total` for VALUES. See the answer I posted.

Comment: Then change the value to sum instead.  click on the litle down arrow by the `count of total` click on `value field setting` and choose `sum`.  See the answer below.

Comment: Got it guys. Now I was wondering, if the total field was not a number and was a random alphanumeric string can you still display using those strings? I tried just now as an example and any text I put under totals after the pivot it defaults it to the number 1.

Comment: No this method only works with numbers not text strings, but that is not what you were showing in your example.

Comment: I understand Scott I just know for the future I will run into that and was asking. Should I make a new posting with that question?

Comment: Yes ask a new question with data that is representative of your data.  Make sure if you have duplicate ID/Type values that you show what you want in the return for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel, format the data like so:

[image]

Choose a cell in these data, go to Insert -> PivotTable, insert it where you would like, and use the following settings:

[image]

This gives

[image]

Under "Design" in the Ribbon (make sure that your PivotTable is selected), go to Grand Totals -> Off for Rows and Columns. This gives

[image]

Click the "Exchange" cell and go toward the top of it, right below the "Column Labels" cell - you will see that the arrowhead will change and you can drag the column:

[image]

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. Ok this worked for numbers. Now let me throw a hypothetical at you. What if the totals field wasn't a number. Let's say it represented a series of unique alphanumeric codes (AF458XYZ for example). Can this still be done?

Comment: @Icebreaker This easily? I'd be inclined to say no, but I'd ask that as a separate question. Personally, I would use `R` rather than Excel for such a case, but that's just me.